# Undefined method in some cases for instance method defined in a subclass

Tags: ruby, instance-method

After much trial-and-error and searching for an existing answer, there seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding I'm having and would love some clarification and/or direction.

Note in advance: I'm using multiple table inheritance and have good reasons for doing so, so no need to direct me back to STI :)

I have a base model:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(*args)
    if self.class == Animal
      raise "Animal cannot be instantiated directly"
    end
    super
  end
end
```

And a sub-class:

```
class Bunny < Animal
  has_one(:bunny_attr)

  def initialize(*args)
    attrs = args[0].extract!(:ear_length, :hop_style)

    super

    self.bunny_attr = BunnyAttr.create!

    bunny_attrs_accessors 

    attrs.each do |key, value|
      self.send("#{key}=", value)
    end

  def bunny_attrs_accessors
    attrs = [:ear_length, :hop_style]

    attrs.each do |att|
      define_singleton_method att do
        bunny_attr.send(att)
      end

      define_singleton_method "#{att}=" do |val|
        bunny_attr.send("#{att}=", val)
        bunny_attr.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And a related set of data

```
class BunnyAttr < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bunny
end
```

If I then do something like this:

```
bunny = Bunny.create!(name: "Foofoo", color: white, ear_length: 10, hop_style: "normal")
bunny.ear_length
Bunny.first.ear_length
```

bunny.ear_length will return "10", while Bunny.first.ear_length will return "undefined method 'ear_length' for #<Bunny:0x0..>

Why is that and how do I get the second call to return a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the code you currently have in initialize to an `after_initialize` callback.

```
after_initialize do
  # the code above...
end
```

When ActiveRecord loads from the database, it doesn't actually call initialize.  When you call `Bunny.first`, ActiveRecord eventually calls the following method:

```
def find_by_sql(sql, binds = [])
  result_set = connection.select_all(sanitize_sql(sql), "#{name} Load", binds)
  column_types = {}

  if result_set.respond_to? :column_types
    column_types = result_set.column_types
  else
    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "the object returned from `select_all` must respond to `column_types`"
  end

  result_set.map { |record| instantiate(record, column_types) }
end
```

And the instantiate method looks like this:

```
 def instantiate(record, column_types = {})
    klass = discriminate_class_for_record(record)
    column_types = klass.decorate_columns(column_types.dup)
    klass.allocate.init_with('attributes' => record, 'column_types' => column_types)
  end
```

And `init_with`...

```
def init_with(coder)
  @attributes   = self.class.initialize_attributes(coder['attributes'])
  @column_types_override = coder['column_types']
  @column_types = self.class.column_types

  init_internals

  @new_record = false

  run_callbacks :find
  run_callbacks :initialize

  self
end
```

`init_internals` just sets some internal variables, like `@readonly`, `@new_record`, etc, so `#initialize` never actually gets called when you load records from the database.  You'll also notice the `run_callbacks :initialize` that does run when you load from the db.

**Note** the above code is extracted from Rails 4.1.1, but much of the initialization process should be the same for other, recent versions of Rails.

**Edit**: I was just thinking about this a little more, and you can remove the code where you define the setter methods and then call them if you delegate the methods to `BunnyAttr`.

```
class Bunny < Animal
  has_one :bunny_attr
  delegate :ear_length, :hop_style, to: :bunny_attr, prefix: false, allow_nil: false
end
```

This will automatically create the getters and setters for `ear_length` and `hop_style`, and it'll track their dirty status for you, too, allowing you to save `bunny_attr` when you call save on `bunny`.  Setting `allow_nil` to false will cause ActiveRecord to throw an error if `bunny_attr` is `nil`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this great explanation!  Wondering if you can clarify a bit more.  I only ended up moving bunny_attr_accessors into the after_initialize as I need the other lines to run when a new Bunny is created.  Once I did that, I was surprised that the     "attrs.each do |key, value| { self.send("#{key}=", value) }"
didn't throw an error since those setters were defined in bunny_attr_accessors.  Wondering if you can shed some light on the order of operations here?

Comment: Well, if you're calling `bunny_attr_accessors` before you call `self.send "#{key}=", value`, then it is defining the setter attributes before you try to set them.  Might I suggest an alternative?  I'll update the answer above.

Comment: No, I had removed bunny_attr_accessors from initialize and only put it in after_initialize, so my guess would have been that the setters would be defined after `self.send`. I forgot about delegation, that seems like a much better solution, but I'm still curious about the order just for future knowledge.  Thanks for all the info!

Comment: Ah, okay, now I understand.  You called `super` on the second line of the `#initialize` method, which called the superclass's `#initialize` method, which fires the same `run_callbacks :initialize`, causing your callback to run before the rest of your initialize method finished running.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation!  I also ended up needing to delegate the setters: `delegate :ear_length, :ear_length=, :hop_style, :hop_style=, to: :bunny_attr, prefix: false, allow_nil: false'

Comment: Ah, yeah, I didn't think about delegating the setters.  Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

The delegation described in the answer from Sean worked perfectly, but I wanted something more generic as I'm going to have quite a few "Animals" and didn't want to have to update the delegate line every time I added a new column to BunnyAttr, etc. and I was trying to move as much code as I could up to the Animal class.

I then stumbled upon [this blog posting](http://www.saturnflyer.com/blog/jim/2013/03/21/ruby-delegate-rb-secrets/) and have decided to go the route of using method_missing in the Bunny class (eventually will define a version in the Animal class where I pass the attr class).

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
  bunny_attr.respond_to?(method_name) ?
  bunny_attr.send(method_name, *args) :
  super
end
```

Would of course like comments on why this is a bad idea, if any.